# How to find an implicit description of the span of a vector set.

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find an *implicit* description of

$$
Span
\left\{
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 \\
4 \\
-6 \\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
2 \\
-5 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\right\}.
$$

That is, I need a set of one or more homogenous equations that characterize the points in the span.

I know that the span of a vector set is the set of all linear combinations of the vectors in the set. I also know that the solution is the set of all $a,b,c$ such that $a+2b+c=0$, but I don't know how to arrive at it.

Comment: You seem to know what a span is and already have the solution.  Can you clarify the question?

Comment: Note that $(a,b,c)=(-2,4,6)$ does **not** satisfy $a+2b+c=0$. But $(-2,4,-6)$ does. So indeed, what is your question?

Comment: @joshphysics   The question is how would I get the solution to a similar exercise if it were not provided in the text.

Comment: @ Dietrich Burde   Yes, you are correct.  I fixed the typo.

Answer (score 1):

A little too long for a comment.

First, I think there's a typo. $(-2,4,6)$ doesn't solve $a + 2b +c = 0$ but
$(-2, 4, -6)$ does.

Second, a hint: look for the orthogonal complement of the space spanned by those two vectors. Or, put another way, look for a way to describe that space as the kernel of some linear transformation or matrix. How you do that will depend on what you can resurrect from your old linear algebra course.

You can follow the steps in the answer here:

[Image and kernel of a matrix transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236541/image-and-kernel-of-a-matrix-transformation)

starting with the matrix

```
-2   1  
 4   2  
-6   5
```

Comment: OK Thanks, but I still don't "get it".  If (a,b,c) is in the span of {(-2,4,-6),(1,2,-5)} then there are real numbers s and t such that -2*s + t = a, 4*s + 2*t = b and -6*s - 5*t = c.  I can see that the solution stating that a + 2*b + c =0 is correct but how would I ever have deduced this?

Comment: I'm sure you learned this (once) in your linear algebra class. Google _find kernel of a matrix_ and you'll get lots of links. At least one of them should help you.

Comment: @ Ethan Bolder.  I sincerely appreciate your reply.  I know how to find the kernel of the linear transformation associated with a matrix.  For what matrix am I supposed to find null space?  I am still completely baffled by this exercise.