# What are subspaces of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Can anyone please tell me what are the subspaces of $A$ ?

[image]

**My Thoughts:**  $\{\alpha I + \beta J : \alpha , \beta \in \mathbb R , \beta > 0 \}$ is not a vector space and it does not contain any  non-zero vector spcae as well.
Can anyone help me ?

Comment: I agree that $A$ is not a subspace.  In fact, $A$ is a matrix (if one thinks about $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as fixed).  Perhaps the subspaces part asks for the subspaces associated to $A$, e.g., the kernel, image, eigenspaces, etc.

Comment: Do not confuse $\{\alpha I+\beta J~:~\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb R,~\beta>0\}$ which is a set of matrices and $A=\alpha I+\beta J$ which is an individual matrix.  The image, the kernel, the left-kernel and the rowspace are colloquially known as the [four fundamental subspaces](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalMatrixSubspaces.html) associated to the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is not a set, it's a matrix. Asking for the "subspaces of $A$" probably means the eigenspaces associated to each eigenvalue of $A$. (The question should be clearer about that)

Comment: I think, as @MichaelBurr pointed out, that they also want the kernel and image of $A$. OP, these can be found from Gaussian elimination, [see this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236541/image-and-kernel-of-a-matrix-transformation) for guidance. There's a ton of resources on the internet on this topic if that thread doesn't help you

Answer (score -1):

The eigen values of A are $\alpha\pm i\beta$. Since beta>0, the eigen values are distinct and complex conjugates and hence A is invertible. So kernel is trivial and range is whole codomain.

Comment: For those who can't understand why we get distinct eigen values, the characteristic polynomial is x^2 -2alpha x + (alpha^2 + beta^2)=0